# How to allow all domains / websites to access my chrome extension from their web pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, opentok

I am using `OpenTok` API in one of our web applications to enable webRTC. While working on screenshare feature, I had to upload `screen share` extension onto my chrome web store.

In the `manifest.json` I have provided the below code to provide access to the websites to communicate with my extension.

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "https://websiteurl1/*",
      "https://websiteurl2/*",
      "https://localhost/*"
    ],
     "accepts_tls_channel_id": false
},
```

How can I make all domains to access my chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable#reference) for manifest.json `extenally_connectable` says:

> **matches** (array of string) - optional
>
> Patterns cannot include wildcard domains nor subdomains of (effective)
>   top level domains;

Seems like it's not possible.

Comment: Then how does AdBlock extensions work? they seem to be working on every site...

Comment: `extenally_connectable` is not something that adblockers use I think. I'd say they're probably using content scripts or intercepting web requests. Externally connectable is used for allowing web pages to pass messages to your Chrome Extension.